# How to prevent iOS safari error alert when trying to open non-installed app?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, safari, mobile-safari

When opening my web page in browser i have an redirection to my app in phone that in code looks like:

```
const urlRedirect = `myapp://`;
const redirect = () => isAndroid() || isIOS() ? (window.location.href = urlRedirect) : null;
window.onload = function () {
 redirect();
 …
}
```

So when app in installed we will be redirected to it, but if it’s not installed we will stay in our web page. In Android all works perfect and if app not installed user will just see the web page, but I got an “Safari cannot open the page because the address in invalid” in iOS/iPhone if app is not installed.

[Invalid url error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRQ9x.png)

How can I handle or prevent showing of this dialog? I don’t need to show any error dialog and also i don’t need any redirecting to App Store.

If app not installed I just want to show user web page without any error dialogs. How can I do this?